# Showing that a wave equation $u_{tt}=ku_{xx}$ has solution $u=0$ if $u(x,0)=u_t(x,0)=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, alternative-proof

> Show that a wave equation $\rho u_{tt}=Tu_{xx}$ has solution $u=0$ if $u(x,0)=u_t(x,0)=0$.

**Thoughts:** This is easy using the general solution to wave equations

$$u(x,t)=\frac12(\phi(x+ct)+\phi(x-ct))+\frac1{2c}\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}\psi(s)\,ds$$

with $c=\sqrt{T/\rho}$ and $\phi$ and $\psi$ as initial displacement and velocity respectively. Obviously the form above will be $0$. However, I'm trying to show that the only solution is $0$ using conservation laws.

**Conservation Laws:** We have $E=KE+PE$ (energy is kinetic plus potential) and $dE/dt=0$. In particular,

$$KE=\frac12\int_D\rho u_t^2\,dx$$
$$PE=\frac12\int_D Tu_x^2\,dx$$

**Question:** I can't think of a good strategy to show that the conservation of energy implies that my PDE has only the trivial solution, even though intuitively it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Why do you think you need the integral term?  It is the sum of two functions, one a function of $x+ct$, the other a function of $x-ct$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $E(t)' =0$ where
$$ E(t) = \frac{1}{2}\int (\rho u_t^2  + T u_x^2) dx = \frac{1}{2}\int (\rho u_t^2  - T u u_{xx}) dx  $$
via integration by parts (assuming there is no wave at infinity). Clearly
$$ E(0) = 0 $$
by the initial conditions. Thus we see
$$ \frac{1}{2}\int (\rho u_t^2  + T u_x^2) dx = 0 \quad \forall t \in \mathbb{R}_+ $$
Since the integrand is non-negative, we see that
$$ u_t = u_x = 0 \quad \forall x,t \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}_{+}$$
along with the initial conditions, we conclude
$$ u \equiv 0 $$

Answer (score 0):

The other way is using that Cauchy problem can have at most one solution, and noting that $u = 0$ is a solution, it is perfectly correct.